# Kibana to do dataviz on non time series data?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, kibana, banana

Im evaluating gap between ELK and SiLK and i would know if it is possible in ELK (using Kibana) to display data not related to time series (let's say a list of products definition).

Thank you in advance

Stp

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is [possible](http://blog.xebia.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/geekshop-kibana-part3.png).

Another [example](https://www.found.no/media/foundation/2014-03-12-article_kibana_twitter_kibana6.png).